# Can I connect 2 wireless router to comcast modem at 2 different locations? and how?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have Comcast modem for Internet for my home. I have connected Wireless router about 80 ft away from modem. I want to add another wireless router closer to modem.

What do I need to use to share one port from modem? can both wireless routers work at the same time

Comment: You can't connect the second router to the first

Comment: @ramhound why not?

Comment: Because the modem is unlikely to have multiple LAN ports and my suggestion is simple work around and results in the same setup

Comment: so [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-One-Router-to-Another-to-Expand-a-Network) isn't what he's asking for? i've personally done this myself. Either I misunderstood his question, or you are. i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need a small switch or hub to provide extra ports. Plug the switch into the modem and the two routers into the switch. The trick is that the modem will latch on to the MAC of whatever device is plugged in. You need to reboot the modem after the switch is plugged in.

Comment: you should probably ask him if he has a cable modem with more than 1 port first, because an ISP like charter actually provides this, in there modem/router hardware (includes 4 ports).